# How can I log unhandeled exception in AppHarbor?

Tags: c#, appharbor

I have a website on appharbor.

I know there is logentries for logs on demand.

But, how can I see all unhandled server-side exceptions?

I have found this snippet (to put int Global.ascx), but couldn't find what are all the required dlls to reference.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        var logEntry = new LogEntry
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Message = exception.Message,
            StackTrace = exception.StackTrace,
        };

        var datacontext = new LogDBDataContext();
        datacontext.LogEntries.InsertOnSubmit(logEntry);
        datacontext.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // failed to record exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AppHarbor already logs application errors](http://blog.appharbor.com/2011/03/28/application-errors), you can inspect them by clicking "Errors" in the menu to the left of the application dashboard.

Another great option is to [add Elmah to your AppHarbor application](http://jefclaes.be/2012/02/adding-elmah-to-appharbor-application.html), but remember to lock down Elmah view.

Should you still want to use the snippet above, then take a look at the [full sample](https://github.com/appharbor/Error-Logging-Example) to see what other dependencies are required.